# Difference between HTML entities for trademark symbol

Tags: html

I'm wondering what's the main difference between the trademark symbol html. Which is the "standard".

I have these 3 ways of doing, but have issues on some WYSIWYG editors.

```
 &#8482;
 &trade; (article)
 &#153; (article)
```

I read this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/tm-symbol-html/) and has me quite confused. Anyone has some suggestions.

> These are not supported by the HTML specification. They should render correctly across browsers and operating systems but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

W3 have their own *Character Entity Reference* available at http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref which lists HTML-friendly character entities.

The trademark symbol has the following:

```
™
&trade;
&TRADE;
&#x02122;
&#8482;
```

This means that browsers *should* handle these and convert all of them appropriately into the ™ character. Which you use is entirely down to preference, however you may find that `&trade;` and `&TRADE;` aren't supported on some browsers so may want to use the others instead.

All realistically do the same thing - they pull and render [Unicode 'Trade Mark Sign' character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) .

It's worth noting though that you can probably get away with just using ™ anyway, without having to reference its character entity code:

```html
<p>Hello™, World™!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `& trade;` if possible.  The others are referencing code point numbers (if that is the correct term) relative to a given character set.